# Find a regexp in awk

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I have a file with a line like this:

```
<div class="cell contentCell bbActiveRow" tabindex="-1" style="width: 150px; left: 77px; display: block;" cellposition="15,2"><div class="cell contentCell bbActiveRow last-child" tabindex="-1" style="width: 150px; left: 697px; display: block;" cellposition="15,6">159</div></div><div class="contentRow bb_row" rowindex="16" style="display: block; top: 429px;"><div class="cell first-child " title="Go to box" tabindex="-1" role="linkAction" cellposition="16,0"><span class="pre-child" style="background-color:#16A765;">&nbsp;</span><span class="link" role="link">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

The important bit I want to catch is the 159 in:

```
,6">159</div>
```

I can catch it fine with grep:

```
cat c |grep  ',6\">[0-9]\+<'
```

Now, what I want to do, is actually catch the number itself (159) and print it out.
Note that the actual file I have has several of those lines. Ideally, only the numbers will print out.

I thought I could do it with awk:

```
cat c | awk ' /,6\">([0-9]\+)/ { print $1 } '
```

But nope, nothing gets printed out.
Having the regexp ready, and knowing that there are several lines in the file with entries that match the expression (with different numbers), how would you squeeze those numbers out?

Comment: not really the best way to do that in my opinion; but if you want to do it like that, can you use gawk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A pragmatic approach:

```
cat c | grep -o ',6\">[0-9]\+<' | awk -F'<|>' '{ print $2 }'
```

- `-o` causes grep to only report the matching part of each line.
- `awk -F'<|>' '{ print $2 }'` then extracts the token between `>` and `<`.

---

As for why your `awk` command didn't work:

- `awk` uses extended regular expressions, in which `+` must NOT be escaped as `\+` to be recognized as a quantifier.
- Even with that fixed, the command wouldn't work, because, by default, `awk` splits by whitespace, so `$2` will simply report the 2nd *whitespace*-separated token on each matching line, irrespective of the regular expression that caused the match.

---

The solution at the top even finds *multiple* matches on a line, but if we assume that there's at most 1, it is *relatively* straightforward to **do it all in `awk`**, *if* you have *GNU* `awk`:

```
cat c | gawk '{ m=gensub(/^.*,6\">([0-9]+)<.*$/, "\\1", "1"); if (m != $0) print m }'
```

- The non-POSIX `gensub()` replaces regex matches and returns the replacement, while crucially also supporting backreferences, which the POSIX `sub()` and `gsub()` functions do not.
- The above matches the entire line, then replaces it with the captured number only (via (escaped) backreference `\1`), and stores the result in a variable. If the variable doesn't equal the input line, a match was captured, and it is printed.

While a solution with POSIX `awk` features only is possible (using `match()`, `RSTART`, `RLENGTH`, `split()`), it would be cumbersome.

---

Finally, *if* you have `xmllint` (OS X does, and *some* Linux distros), consider [guido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574997/45375) for a solution that performs actual HTML parsing and applies an XPath query, and is therefore more robust.

Comment: I never knew the -o option in grep. That was the key! Thank you!

Comment: @Merc: Glad to hear it. `-o` is not part of POSIX (see http://man.cx/grep), but at least GNU grep and BSD/OS X grep do support it.

Answer (score 3):

This oneliner is an alternate way to do that (using an xpath expression which matches div elements containing a cellposition attribute value ending with ',6'):

```
# xmllint --html test.html --xpath '//div[substring(@cellposition, string-length(@cellposition) - 1)=",6"]/text()' 
159
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to do it +1

Comment: Nice, though `xmllint` is not standard on all platforms, unfortunately (comes with OS X and _some_ Linux distros (e.g., Fedora), but notably not Ubuntu).

Comment: @mklement0 yeah there is people on this site which have been brutalized for trying to parse text inside html....